# Controlling back button using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I have a index page and many button on that index page. Clicking those button page will go to some other pages. I have this code on `index.htlm`

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-mobile/cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert("Are you sure !!")
}

<body onLoad="onLoad()"> </body>
```

So when I am in the index page back button should only give that alert. I have no problem with that, the alert is showing properly but back button is disabled from other page also.

Comment: Plz any one give me some reply

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your script inside page divs. This may help.

Comment: Try to handle back button click only on the index.html page. Or hanlde it in different way on index.html.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the page in your function, so it reacts equally for every page. Try this:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("Are you sure !!");
   }
   else {
       navigator.app.backHistory()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download  more recent cordova-2.0.0.js
2. Place it in your root directory (next to index.html)
3. Load it in your `<head>` section

> ```
> <head>
>      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js">
>      <!-- Other JS files .... -->
> </head>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding after your alert:

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```